# submit doesn't trigger required error on untouched custom form control element

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I use Angular 13.1.1 to write my app.

I have a simple login form with email and password, i wanted to create my own form control component for the email, to add my own validators and `mat-error` for error messages and also to allow parent components to detect errors and fetch value and to be able to use it as a form control.

the problem that i'm having that the submit button outside of the component doesn't trigger the `required` error. in general i debug the validate function of my custom form control and clicking the submit button doesn't trigger it.

[image: after clicking the submit button]

lets start with the custom email component.

this is the class:

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, forwardRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  ControlValueAccessor, FormBuilder, FormGroup, NG_VALIDATORS,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  ValidationErrors,
  Validator,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tuxin-form-email-input',
  templateUrl: './tuxin-form-email-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tuxin-form-email-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi:true,
      useExisting:  TuxinFormEmailInputComponent,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: TuxinFormEmailInputComponent
    }
  ]
})
export class TuxinFormEmailInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator, OnInit {

  newChildForm: FormGroup;

  onChange = (email: string) => {};

  onTouched = () => {};

  onValidationChange: any = () => {};

  touched = false;

  disabled = false;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.newChildForm = this.fb.group({
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    });
  }



  writeValue(email: string) {
    this.newChildForm.get('email')?.setValue(email, { emitEvent: true });
  }

  registerOnChange(onChange: any) {
    this.onChange = onChange;
  }

  registerOnTouched(onTouched: any) {
    this.onTouched = onTouched;
  }

  markAsTouched() {
    if (!this.touched) {
      this.onTouched();
      this.touched = true;
    }
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onValidationChange = fn;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newChildForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      this.onChange(val.email);

      this.onValidationChange();
    });
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
    disabled ? this.newChildForm.disable() : this.newChildForm.enable();
  }

  get email() {
    return this.newChildForm.get('email');
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (this.newChildForm?.invalid) {
      return { invalid: true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="newChildForm">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="email" formControlName="email"/>
  <mat-error i18n *ngIf="email?.hasError('required')">Email is required</mat-error>
  <mat-error i18n *ngIf="email?.hasError('email')">Email Invalid</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

the template of the component that uses the email component:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
  <h4 i18n>Login</h4>
  <app-tuxin-form-email-input formControlName="email"></app-tuxin-form-email-input>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password" />
    <mat-hint i18n>8-30 characters length</mat-hint>
    <mat-error i18n *ngIf="password?.hasError('required')">Password is required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="primary" i18n>Login</button>
</div>
</form>
```

and the class of the main component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
import {GraphqlService} from '../graphql.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-tab',
  templateUrl: './login-tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-tab.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginTabComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private toastr: ToastrService,
              private gql:GraphqlService) {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [''],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(8), Validators.max(30)]]
    });
  }

  get email() {
    return this.loginForm.get('email');
  }

  get password() {
    return this.loginForm.get('password');
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.status === 'INVALID') {
      this.toastr.error("please fill all forms properly");
    } else {
      const value = this.loginForm.value;
      const email = value.email;
      const password = value.password;
      this.gql.login(email,password).subscribe(({data})=>{
        console.info(data);
      })
      console.log(value);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
}
```

if I touch the actual email component, the errors appear right away,

[image: focus and unfocus the email component]

but the submit button doesn't initiate the validate function, any ideas why and how to correct it?

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to seperate the email field into another component? I suggest you to have both fields in a single component.

Comment: since each has a different input type with different mask and different validators i would like to create a component for each type of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem. That's typically an angular issue I think, child -> parent relation works fine with CVA, but parent -> child are more complex tho.

Especially because `email` formControl is not fully binded to `loginForm` when accessed into the CVA.

Our solution is to have a submitted `submitFormEvent$` and pass it to the component, so that you can manage when to trigger submission validation.

In your case it'll be:

```
import ...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tuxin-form-email-input',
  templateUrl: './tuxin-form-email-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tuxin-form-email-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi:true,
      useExisting:  TuxinFormEmailInputComponent,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: TuxinFormEmailInputComponent
    }
  ]
})
export class TuxinFormEmailInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator, OnInit {
  @Input() submitEvent$ = new Observable<void>()

  newChildForm: FormGroup;

  onChange = (email: string) => {};

  onTouched = () => {};

  onValidationChange: any = () => {};

  touched = false;

  disabled = false;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
   ...
  }

  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newChildForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      this.onChange(val.email);
      this.onValidationChange();
    });
    this.submitEvent$.subscribe(() => {
          this.newChildForm.markAsTouched()
      })
  }
...
}
```

And for the base component

```
import ...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-tab',
  templateUrl: './login-tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-tab.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginTabComponent implements OnInit {
  submitFormEvent$ = new Subject<void>()

  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private toastr: ToastrService,
              private gql:GraphqlService) {
    ...
  }

  get email() {
    return this.loginForm.get('email');
  }

  get password() {
    return this.loginForm.get('password');
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitFormEvent.next();
    if (this.loginForm.status === 'INVALID') {
      this.toastr.error("please fill all forms properly");
    } else {
      const value = this.loginForm.value;
      const email = value.email;
      const password = value.password;
      this.gql.login(email,password).subscribe(({data})=>{
        console.info(data);
      })
      console.log(value);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
}
```

Comment: this.newChildForm.markAllAsTouched();

Answer (score 0):

The above works, but I was able to get it working without having to manually provide the input using the following approach instead.  Just thought I'd post for anyone else in the future:

The important parts in the sub-component:

```
constructor(
    @Optional() private formGroup: FormGroupDirective,
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    .....
) {}

ngOnInit() { 
      this.formGroup.ngSubmit.subscribe(value => {
        this.form.markAllAsTouched();
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      });
}
```

So to apply that to the above example:

```
import ...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tuxin-form-email-input',
  templateUrl: './tuxin-form-email-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tuxin-form-email-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi:true,
      useExisting:  TuxinFormEmailInputComponent,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: TuxinFormEmailInputComponent
    }
  ]
})
export class TuxinFormEmailInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator, OnInit {

  newChildForm: FormGroup;

  onChange = (email: string) => {};

  onTouched = () => {};

  onValidationChange: any = () => {};

  touched = false;

  disabled = false;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, @Optional private formGroup: FormGroupDirective) {
   ...
  }

  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newChildForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      this.onChange(val.email);
      this.onValidationChange();
    });
    this.newChildForm.ngSubmit.subscribe(() => {
          this.newChildForm.markAllAsTouched();
          this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      })
  }
...
}
```

Hope that helps someone!